# Double associative array or 1(n) loop more efficient?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a WebSocket server using NodeJS and I really need to be able to look up a "class" by both the socket and the id of the user.

So I'm trying to figure out what would be more efficient, and why.

```
var usersBySocket = {};
var usersById = {}

// ID is pulled from database in NetworkClient constructor.
server.on('connection', function(client) {
    var networkClient = new NetworkClient(client);
    usersBySocket[client] = networkClient;
    usersById[networkClient.getId()] = networkClient;
});

// When needing to send a specific user some data
// based on his user id (IE: Messaging).
// usersById(...).send(...);
```

OR

```
var users = {}

server.on('connection', function(client) {
    users[client] = new NetworkClient(socket);
});

function getUserById(id) {
    for(var uid in users) {
        if(uid == id) return users[uid];
    } 
    return undefined;
}

// Then when I needto use it, call it like so:
// getUserById(..).getSocket().send(..);
```

I'm leaning towards the first option, but I'm not sure exactly how JavaScript handles storing the values, if each "associative array" stores by value and not by reference, it's a complete waste. I especially don't want obsessive memory copy.

Comment: Object values are **always** references.

Comment: @Pointy - All I needed to know ;).

Comment: I don't think you wrote what you meant in the second version. Shouldn't it be `for (client in users) { if (users[client].userid == id) ...}`?

Comment: None of them really make much sense? The first one stores the same instance of a function in two objects, and the second one uses a loop to do something that could be done with just `users[id]` instead of the function ? Just storing the connection in one object with the Client as key, and then using a simple map object with ID's as keys and the ClientId as a value seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are stored by reference. But the first option is always going to use more memory for the `usersById` object.

The second option uses less memory, but you are trying to do a linear search to find the user with the right id, this is not efficient.